# Why does the system not recognize my fonts?

Tags: root-access, system, fonts

My phone is a rooted Nexus S running the custom ROM [Replicant](http://replicant.us). I copied twelve font files comprising three fonts ([Arimo](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Arimo), [Cousine](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cousine), and [Tinos](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Tinos)) from my computer to the SD card, used a root file manager to copy the files to /system/fonts, and then rebooted the phone. Yet I am still unable to use these fonts. On par with the other font files in the folder, they are indeed .ttf files. For example, when I view this HTML file in the HTML viewer:

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style>

.arimo {
    font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

.cousine {
    font-family: "Cousine", monospace;
}

.tinos {
    font-family: "Tinos", serif;
}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Font Test</title>

</head>

<body>

<p class="arimo">Arimo paragraph</p>

<p class="cousine">Cousine paragraph</p>

<p class="tinos">Tinos paragraph</p>

</body>

</html>

The paragraphs display in Roboto, Droid Sans Mono, and Droid Serif respectively. Why does the system not recognize the newly installed fonts? Is there some configuration file I need to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Problem <del>mostly, but not entirely,</del> solved. For <del>Arimo</del> whatever font you want to install, you need to insert this text between the <familyset> tags in the file /system/etc/system_fonts.xml:

```
<family>
  <nameset>
    <name>the name of your font</name>
    <name>arial</name>
    <name>helvetica</name>
  </nameset>
  <fileset>
    <file>Arimo-Regular.ttf</file>
    <file>Arimo-Bold.ttf</file>
    <file>Arimo-Italic.ttf</file>
    <file>Arimo-BoldItalic.ttf</file>
  </fileset>
</family>
```

And remove the designations of "arial" and "helvetica" from the Roboto entry. <del>The reason this is not entirely solved is it works only in the browser and not the HTML viewer.</del>